# CSV generator with function fputcsv and loop

Tags: php, html, csv

How should I use tabulate?

```
$naglowek = "ID,\t Imię,\t Nazwisko,\t Data urodzenia,\t Miasto,\t EMAIL";
$naglowek = explode(";",$naglowek); // header
fputcsv($fp, $naglowek); 
while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $ciag = '';
    $ciag =  $r['id'].','.$r['name'].','.$r['surName'].','.$r['dateOfBirth'].','.$r['city'].','.$r['email'];
    $ciag = explode(";",$ciag);
    fputcsv($fp, $ciag,"\t");
}
```

I added "\t" but it isn't working.

Below is question, what somebody answered.
I made a CSV generator for my client. It should get data from DB (mysqli).
The code is :

```
while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $someVariable = $r['id'].','.$r['name'].','.$r['surName'].','.$r['dateOfBirth'].','.
  $r['city'].','.$r['email'];
}
```

It is working. But I go to next step to use a function **fputcsv**. It is from PHP5. 
This is how my DB looks: 
[image: My DB]
 In PHPManual fputcsv is using like:

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);
```

How can I use my data to this array ? My data will be from DataBase and will be generated dynamically by the loop above.

Comment: No the PHP manual is not saying that. After that block, it does a foreach round the array, adding one row in at a time. It would equate in your code to having `fputcsv($fh, $r);` inside your while loop.

Comment: `while($r = ...) { fputcsv($file, $r); }`. that's it.

Comment: You can use **implode** to build string from array. `$someVariable = implode(',', $r);`

Comment: I did it. Now I need tabulate it. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way:

```
$fp = fopen('out.csv', 'w');

while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    fputcsv($fp, $r);
}

fclose($fp);
```

For each line that fetch from the database, it will include in out.csv file.